# Why can't I receive data from HTML in my Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on implementing a user registration feature. However, no matter how much I modify it, I can't seem to receive the data in my Controller. Why might this be happening?
-The environment I am developing in is java17, springboot3, spring security6, jpa, and mysql.

```
MainController
```

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up/save")
public String Registration(@ModelAttribute("user") UserAccountDto user
) {
    log.info("[MainController] user: {}", user);
    System.out.println("[MainController] user: " + user);

    userAccountService.saveUser(user);
    return "redirect:/login?success";
}
```

---

```
UserAccountDto
```

```
public record UserAccountDto(
        String userId,
        String userPassword,
        String email,
        String nickname,
        String memo,
        LocalDateTime createdAt,
        String createdBy,
        LocalDateTime modifiedAt,
        String modifiedBy
) {

    public static UserAccountDto of(String userId, String userPassword, String email, String nickname, String memo) {
        return new UserAccountDto(userId, userPassword, email, nickname, memo, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

---

```
UserAccountServiceImpl
```

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@Transactional
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserAccountServiceImpl implements UserAccountService {

    private final UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public void saveUser (UserAccountDto user) {

        UserAccount saveUser = UserAccount.of(user.userId(), user.userPassword(), user.email(), user.nickname(), user.memo());
        saveUser.setUserPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.userPassword()));

        Optional<UserAccount> existingUser = userAccountRepository.findById(user.toEntity().getUserId());

        if (existingUser.isEmpty()) {

            userAccountRepository.saveAndFlush(saveUser);

//            return new ResponseEntity("success", HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
//            return new ResponseEntity("fail", HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
SecurityConfig
```

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                    .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations()).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                            "/",
                            "/articles",
                            "/articles/search-hashtag",
                            "/sign-up").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(
                    form -> form
                            .loginPage("/login")
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                            .usernameParameter("username") 
                            .passwordParameter("password") 
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                            .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(logout -> logout
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")) 
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/") 
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true) 
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") 
                    .permitAll()
            );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository) {
        return username ->
                userAccountRepository.findById(username)            
                        .map(UserAccountDto::from)     
                        .map(BoardPrincipal::from)     
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No exist user - username: " + username));
    }
```

I'm working on implementing a user registration feature. However, no matter how much I modify it, I can't seem to receive the data in my Controller. Why might this be happening?
-The environment I am developing in is java17, springboot3, spring security6, jpa, and mysql.

Comment: What data are you trying to access in your controller? Could you also share the configuration files?

Comment: I think you should share the UserAccount class. Also, share the properties file to make the question more understandable.